# isinstance() to check Keras Layer Type on Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras, deep-learning

I get a list of pre-built Keras layers for a model as:

```
def build_model(layers):
```

And I want to build a Keras Functional API model a:

```
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

So for achieving this, I used:

```
inputs = list()
outputs = list()
for layer in layers:
    if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Input):
        inputs.append(layer)
    else:
        outputs.append(layer)
```

But the problem is, the pre-built Keras Input Layer no-longer holds the datatype: Input, but is instead a Tensor like so:

> Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, None, None), dtype=float32)

Is there a solution for this. The function signature cannot be changed unfortunately, but if there is a workaround - let me know (really stuck here).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Ramsha Siddiqui, Kindly provide more details on your model as well as the minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function `isinstance` is giving problem, we can resolve this issue by using the `Names of Layers`.

For example, let's build a simple model using the code below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow import keras

x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

Let's verify the Architecture using the command, `model.summary()` and it is shown below:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 32)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                528       
=================================================================
Total params: 528
Trainable params: 528
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If we observe the names of the Layers, `Input Layer` has a prefix of **input**.

Or in other words, the code,

```
print('Name of First Layer is ', layers[0].name)
print('Name of Second Layer is ', layers[1].name)
```

results in

```
Name of First Layer is  input_2
Name of Second Layer is  dense_1
```

So, we can modify our logic as shown below:

```
layers = model.layers
inputs = []
outputs = []

for layer in layers:
  # Check if a Layer is an Input Layer using its name
  if 'input' in layer.name:
    inputs.append(layer)
  else:
    outputs.append(layer)

print('Inputs List is ', inputs)
print('Outputs List is ', outputs)
```

Output of above code is:

```
Inputs List is  [<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7fef788154e0>]
Outputs List is  [<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7fef78845fd0>]
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Hi! Yes that is what I ended up using. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `keras.layers.Input` with `keras.layers.InputLayer` like

```
for layer in layers:
 if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.InputLayer):
  inputs.append(layer)
 else:
  outputs.append(layer)
```

This worked fine for me.